# Not seeing the complete resultset from LISTAGG in EVALUATE_AGGR

Tags: oracle, analytics, evaluate, obiee

I'm using the following function to present a column

**Column Formula**

```
EVALUATE_AGGR('LISTAGG(%1,%2) 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %3 desc)',
"Product"."NameCode",',',"Product"."NameCode")
```

The resultant column should be resulting a comma separated names of the product code names(each code is of two characters).

The issue here is, I'm seeing a maximum of 7 Product Code Names(along with 6 commas in between them) resulting in a maximum of 20 characters. Even though the resultant set has more than 7 product codenames.

Do we have a limit in `OBIEE`, with respect to the number of characters being displayed to be 20. Can this setting be changed. If it can, where can we change it.

Could you please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

USE A CAST

**CAST(**
EVALUATE_AGGR('LISTAGG(%1,%2) 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %3 desc)',
"Product"."NameCode",',',"Product"."NameCode") **AS CHAR(250))**